# Replace first line in text file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

i want to replace first line in another text file using sed.

In the replaced line must be $variable.

Comment: [read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: `sed` really isn't designed for this; you can't pass variables to `sed`, you can only build a `sed` script dynamically, which means you are responsible for escaping any characters in `$variable` that need to be escaped.

Comment: You can escape a variable easily with systemd-escape.

Answer (score 1):

The only (reasonably simple) way to do this safely is to

1. Remove the first line.
2. Combine the modified file with the new first line in a temporary file.
3. Replace the original file with the temporary file.

One way to do that is

```
{ printf '%s\n' "$variable"; sed '1d' original.txt; } > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt original.txt
```

Comment: If you're looking to use temporary files it is best to either create the files in /tmp or remove the temporary file after use.

Comment: The temp file *is* removed, in the sense that it is being renamed to (thus overwriting) the original file.

Answer (score -1):

```
var1=$(systemd-escape $var) 
sed -ri '1s@^.*$@'"$var1"'@' filename
```

Where $var references your dynamic variable, we concentrate on the first line and then replace anything from the start to the end of the line with the var variable. Pay attention to the position of the single quotes which will encompass the expansion of the variable into the sed statement.

Comment: Adding "belts and braces", you can escape variable var with systemd-escape and the quote the variable returned (var1)

Comment: `systems-escape` is designed to create valid `systemd` unit names, not `sed` commands.